# No operator matches these operands: visual studio c++ window forms error

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    long mb = 15001;
    long sb = 1500001;
    long msb = 25000001;

    if (tc < mb)
    {

    }
}
```

Im new to programming and im currently trying to develop an app for a school project that takes 2 numerical inputs and 1 string input in c++ windows form via a textbox to give a required output. Here im having an issue where i can't use the less than in my condition. i get the error "no operator "<" matches these operands". How do i fix this.

Thank you

Comment: I changed the tag to [c++cli], as that is what you are actually programming in. What is the type of `tc`?

Comment: What is tc....?

Comment: @Botje tc is the name of the textbox that i am using to get the input